# How do I create a new Log for this team whilst creating the team?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my team model

```
    public partial class TeamModel
    {
        public TeamModel()
        {
            this.Players = new HashSet<PlayerModel>();

        }

        public int TeamModelId { get; set; }

        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
        public int DivisionId { get; set; }

        public LogModel TeamLog { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Under")]
        public int UnderId { get; set; }

        public virtual LogModel Log { get; set; }
        public virtual SchoolModel School { get; set; }
        public virtual DivisionModel Division { get; set; }
        public virtual UnderModel Under { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PlayerModel> Players { get; set; }
```

This is my log model

```
    public class LogModel
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("Team")]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        public int Played { get; set; }
        public int Win { get; set; }
        public int Draw { get; set; }
        public int Lost { get; set; }
        public int GoalsFor { get; set; }
        public int GoalsAgainst { get; set; }
        public int GoalDifference { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Season")]
        public int SeasonId { get; set; }

        public virtual SeasonModel Season { get; set; }
        public virtual TeamModel Team { get; set; }

    }
```

and this is where I create a new team and also where I try to create  new log for that specific team in the process.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TeamModelId,TeamName,SchoolId,DivisionId,UnderId")] TeamModel teamModel)
        {
                teamModel.TeamLog = new LogModel();

                teamModel.TeamLog.Draw = 0;
                teamModel.TeamLog.GoalDifference = 0;
                teamModel.TeamLog.GoalsAgainst = 0;
                teamModel.TeamLog.GoalsFor = 0;
                teamModel.TeamLog.Lost = 0;
                teamModel.TeamLog.Played = 0;
                teamModel.TeamLog.Points = 0;
                teamModel.TeamLog.Win = 0;
                teamModel.TeamLog.SeasonId = db.Seasons.ToList().Last().SeasonId;

                db.Teams.Add(teamModel);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.DivisionId = new SelectList(db.Divisions, "DivisionId", "DivisionName", teamModel.DivisionId);
            ViewBag.SchoolId = new SelectList(db.Schools, "SchoolId", "SchoolName", teamModel.SchoolId);
            ViewBag.UnderId = new SelectList(db.Under, "UnderID", "UnderName", teamModel.UnderId);
            return View(teamModel);
        }
```

The error that i get when i try adding a new log to the team like this is

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error
>   occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

and the inner exception is

> UpdateException: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent
>   operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints,
>   model requirements, or store-generated values.

I looked for a solution on the internet and I failed to find anything that worked. I think my problem is how I was trying to find the solution. I searched for the error but it didn't seem like the solutions solved the problem I was having here. I have spent a few days trying to create a Log when I create a team.

Comment: P.S I created the database using the code first approach

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I know you are looking for a code first approach, but I'm just wondering if you looked into AFTER INSERT triggers at all. https://www.tutorialgateway.org/after-insert-triggers-in-sql-server/ . It'll allow you to automatically create a TeamLog anytime a new TeamModel is inserted.